# Cannot read property 0 of undefined - even with Conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot realize what I'm doing wrong in the following scenario:

I have an array , called `arrayOfChildren` , which is initiated like this:

```
const [arrayOfChildren,setArrayOfChildren]=React.useState([])
```

Given a handler function, I want to push an array with objects into the `arrayOfChildren`, which will subsequently have the following form:

```
const arr=[[{"A":"trial","B":"test"},{"hey":"Test"}],[{"A":"trial","B":"test"},{"hey":"Test"}],[{"A":"trial","B":"test"},{"hey":"Test"}],[{"A":"trial","B":"test"},{"hey":"Test"}]]`
```

, so the form of the pushed array is `[{},{}]`

My handler is the following:

```
const handleAdditionOfSubGroup=(addChildGroup)=>{
        setArrayOfChildren([
            ...arrayOfChildren,
            addChild
        ])            
    }
```

And this is how I'm returning it :

```
{arrayOfChildren.length>0 && 
          arrayOfChildren.map((item,index)=>{

              return <MyResponsivePieChart 
              ourObject={item[index]}
              key={'item-' + item[0][0].id}
              />
          })}
```

When I did try to see what's happening by logging the array, it always showed empty, even though `addChild` was showing properly. Thank you !

Comment: `item[0][0].id` seems to be the culprit. For testing, change it for `index`

Comment: What exactly is `item[0][0].id` meant to achieve? It looks like `item` would be an array of objects, so the second `[0]` doesn't make sense, and none of your example objects have an `id` anyway?

Comment: What's in `addChild` in the `handleAdditionOfSubGroup` function?

Comment: @AndorPolgar  addChild is an array that contains objects , where each object had the .id property

Comment: @DBS I have tried to change it but it also doesnt work..

Comment: @malarres I have tried but yet still no success...

Comment: `item[0][0].id` - you're already looping through the internal array so it should possibly be `item[0].id`. Btw, you don't need `arrayOfChildren.length>0` as map will work only if there are values in the array.

Comment: There could be several reasons why the `arrayOfChildren` is empty, but we would need to see more of your code to figure it out.

Comment: Seems like changing `item[0][0].id` to `item[0].id` has cleared the previous error , yet It now shows that `item[index]` is not in the form `[{},{}...]` ...

Comment: The `index` here corresponds to the primary array and you are using it with the `item` which is the secondary array.

Comment: @Andor Polgar the mentioned code is all I have regarding `arrayOfChildren` , yet I'm certain that the array that was supposed to be pushed into it is indeed existent as I have seen it  in the log

Comment: @parkourkarthik Damn !! Just realized, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below corrections in the code would help I believe.

```
{arrayOfChildren.map((item,index)=>{
          return <MyResponsivePieChart 
          ourObject={item[0]}
          key={'item-' + item[0].id}
          />
      })}
```

Comment: Thank you! This indeed cleared the previous error, but for some reason, `item` is not in the format of `[{},{},{}]` , which triggers an error for the `MyResponsivePieChart ` component. Do you maybe know why?

Comment: then I believe it should be `ourObject={item}`?? So, basically it is the secondary array which has the format that you require.

Comment: @ parkourkarthik Yes , exactly , thats what I thougth too , yet it shows another error now. Yes , the secondary array is the one that I want to pass as ourObject to the `MyResponsivePieChart ` component